# Почему меняется значение первичного ключа?

Tags: entity-framework

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста по вопросу. Есть код контроллера

```
public dbWork db = new dbWork();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Model model)
        {
            model.DT = DateTime.Now;
            db.WorkData.Add(model); //Интересует эта часть
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Datas = db.WorkData;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Так же есть бд sqlCE к ней я обращаюсь через EntityFramework 6. Вопрос в том что в этой бд есть столбик ID (int) этот столбик является ключом, с автоинкрементом и обязательным. То есть ID из вьюшки я туда не передаю, он подставляется в бд автоматом. Так из вьюхи в этот метод действия идет модель без ID и следовательно при создании объекта модели ID = 0(по умолчанию). А БД уже когда принимает объект модели у себя автоинкрементирует как надо. Но почему-то у меня происходит следующее, БД делает все как надо, и потом модель я передаю во вьюху. Я предполагаю, что в модели ID = 0 (в БД понятное дело что произошел автоинкремент и уже значение ID другое). Во вьюхе пишу @Html.DesplayFor(x => x.ID) но оно выводит ID который был автоинкрементирован из БД, хотя я же передал модель где ID =0 (по умолчанию). Почему так получилось ???
Модель на всякий случай

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace miniChat.Models
{
    public class Model
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime DT { get; set; }
    }
    public class dbWork : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model> WorkData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Кусочек вьюхи

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <span style="color:red;">User</span><span>@Html.Label("Name")</span><br />
            @Html.TextBox("Name");<br />
            <span style="color:red;">@Html.Label("Message")</span><br />
            @Html.TextArea("Message");<br />
            @Html.Display("ID") //Почему отображается ид из бд если этот ид должен браться из модели и поумолчанию быть равным нулю
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам "на пальцах" или академически?

"На пальцах": при выполнении `db.SaveChanges();` все автогенерируемые базой поля загружаются обратно в модель. Это сделано специально, потому что такая автоматическая загрузка - единственный способ получить `Id` добавленной записи.

Академически: после выполнения `db.SaveChanges();` ваша модель переходит из состояния `Added` в состояние `Unchanged`. В таком состоянии у нее должен быть заполнен первичный ключ, что и наблюдается.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Кошмар, сколько нюансов. Интересно сколько лет надо все это учить чтобы вникнуть ? Не по теме , как подписаться на емайл рассылку ответов, а то раньше при ответе приходило письмо, теперь не пойму почему - не приходит